AndroidFriendlyRandomHolder class not found error after upgrade to quarkus 3.14.4
Just upgraded a working app from quarkus 3.12.1 to build with 3.14.4, and started getting the error below when doing a native container build (on a Mac for linux), using
./mvnw clean package -Dnative -DskipTests
-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true 


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
io.opentelemetry.sdk.internal.AndroidFriendlyRandomHolder
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.loadClass(NativeImageClassLoader.java:637)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
at io.quarkus.runner.Feature.runtimeReinitializedClasses(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runner.Feature.beforeAnalysis(Unknown Source)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$9(NativeImageGenerator.java:773)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:90)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:773)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:592)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:550)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:539)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:721)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:143)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:98)

I downgraded the quarkus platform version to 3.12.1 to verify error was not pre-existing, and as expected the error went away with no other changes, and then it re-manifests itself when moving back up to 3.14.4.
Has anyone else seen this?

Please open an issue, this is likely a bug we need to fix in Quarkus
